Few questions on feasible and tangent cones at the boundary point of the closure of an open set: just brief answers with references are enough.
Let $U$ be an open domain in $\mathbb{R}^n.$ The setup I use for domains with $C^1$ boundary is [here][1]. The feasible cone at a boundary point $x\in \partial{U}$ is defined by:
$$F_x(\bar{U}):=\{v\in \mathbb{R}^n: \exists t_0 > 0 \text{ so that }  x + tv \in \bar{U} \forall t \in (0, t_0)\}.$$
We also define the tangent cone to $\bar{U}$ at $x$ by:
$$
T_x(\bar{U}) = \{ v \in \mathbb R^n \mid \exists \{t_n\} \subset (0,\infty), \{x_n\} \subset \bar{U} : t_n \searrow 0, (x_n - x)/t_n \to v\}.
$$
Finally, we define $\bar{U}$ to be locally convex at $x$ if $\exists r > 0: B(x;r)\cap \bar{U}$ is convex.
For me, it's only necessary to know the answer (yes/no/under what conditions yes) to the many questions of mine below, with some references where I can find them, as I didn't find them by searching on the internet. I don't need the proof if they're involved, as these questions arise from problems from another area that are my main focus. Sorry for too many questions, but they're all related, so I put them together. Again, Yes/No/Conditions for Yes, with references are enough :)
1) Feasible cone of the complement: Is the following always true?
$$F_x(\bar{U})\cup F_x( \overline{\mathbb{R}^d \setminus U}) = \mathbb{R}^d, F_x(\bar{U})\cap F_x(\overline{\mathbb{R}^d \setminus U}) = F_x({\partial{U}})?$$
It seems to me that it should follow from
$$F_x(A \cup B)= F_x(A) \cup F_x(B), F_x(A \cap B)= F_x(A) \cap F_x(B)?$$
Wo we need any condition on $U$ at all to guarantee the above?
2) Tangent cone of the complement: Under what conditions on $U$ is the following true?
$$T_x(\bar{U})\cup T_x( \overline{\mathbb{R}^d \setminus U}) = \mathbb{R}^d, T_x(\bar{U})\cap T_x(\overline{\mathbb{R}^d \setminus U}) = T_x({\partial{U}})?$$
Is convexity/local convexity at $x$ the weakest condition we can put?
3) Lebesgue measure of the feasible cones at the boundary:
In relation to the above two questions, when can we say that the Lebesgue measure of
$T_x({\partial{U}})$ is zero? Same question for feasible direction cones. Same question for
$T_x(\bar{U})\cap T_x( \overline{\mathbb{R}^d \setminus U}), F_x(\bar{U})\cap F_x( \overline{\mathbb{R}^d \setminus U})$
4) Is local convexity at $x$ enough to guarantee that $\overline{F_x(\bar{U})}=T_x{\bar{U}}.$ In the resources I find, I always noted that they assumed global convexity of $U,$ but tangent and feasible directions should be local constructs.
[1]: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2368745/equivalent-definitions-of-c1-boundary#:~:text=An%20open%20set%20%CE%A9%E2%8A%82,xN%E2%88%921)%7D.
